List of List of Entities in Java Spring Boot
I'm trying to store this type of data
[
    1: [
        {
           "id":"1"
        },
        {

           "id":"2"
        },
    ],
    2: [
        {
           "id":"2"
        },
        {
           "id":"3"
        },
        {
           "id":"4"
        }
    ]
]

within this class
public class TripItinerary {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "trip_itinerary_id")
    private List<List<Place>> itinerary;
}

where Place is an entity stored in a 'place' table.
Currently, I am getting a 'One To Many' attribute value type should not be 'List' error.
I've tried creating another entity with List<Place>, but I do not have any use case with individual List<Place> objects, so I feel like it is a waste of resources. Is there a better way to handle nested List<List<Objects>> in Spring Boot?

this looks like a many to many to me

One List belongs to only one List<List>.

Storing nested List<List<Place>> directly within a JPA entity isn't straightforward because JPA doesn't support such nested collections directly. Instead, you can model this using additional entity classes and join tables to maintain the structure while still adhering to the relational database principles
ItinerarySegment.java

public class ItinerarySegment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "itinerary_segment_id")
    private List<Place> places;

    // Getters and Setters
}



TripItinerary.java:

public class TripItinerary {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "trip_itinerary_id")
    private List<ItinerarySegment> itinerary;

    // Getters and Setters
}

In service.java
public void saveTripItinerary() {
    Place place1 = new Place();
    place1.setName("Place 1");

    Place place2 = new Place();
    place2.setName("Place 2");

    ItinerarySegment segment1 = new ItinerarySegment();
    segment1.setPlaces(Arrays.asList(place1, place2));

    Place place3 = new Place();
    place3.setName("Place 3");

    Place place4 = new Place();
    place4.setName("Place 4");

    ItinerarySegment segment2 = new ItinerarySegment();
    segment2.setPlaces(Arrays.asList(place3, place4));

    TripItinerary tripItinerary = new TripItinerary();
    tripItinerary.setItinerary(Arrays.asList(segment1, segment2));

    tripItineraryRepository.save(tripItinerary);
}

